# Jenkins shell script returned exit code 1 when the searched string isn't exsist

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm tring the following at Jenkins in aim to search strings of failures in jobs. 
This will run on daily basis.

```
def sd = "2020" + "${env.START_DATE}" + "0000"
def ed = "2020" + "${env.END_DATE}" + "2359.59"

pipeline {
    agent {label "master"}
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {

                print(sd)
                sh 'echo "Hello World"'
                sh """
                    pwd
                    #rm end-time start-time
                    #rm $WORKSPACE/$PARSING_OUTPUT
                    touch -t $sd $WORKSPACE/start-time
                    touch -t $ed $WORKSPACE/end-time
                    find /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/. -type f -newer $WORKSPACE/start-time  ! -newer $WORKSPACE/end-time -name '*' -exec grep $SEARCH_STRING /dev/null {} + >> $WORKSPACE/$PARSING_OUTPUT
                    ls -ltr
                """
            }
        post {
                always {
                    echo "sending mail"
                    //mail to: 'e@s.com',
                    //subject: "Parse Jenkins log",
                    //body: "TBD"
                    //body: "${env.BUILD_URL} has result ${currentBuild.result}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that if the string I'm looking for isn't exsist. the job fail..
Console output display `ERROR: script returned exit code 1`.
I tried adding `#!/bin/sh` that will allow me to execute with no option - didn't help.
any suggestions ?

Comment: Parameter `returnStatus` of `sh` step.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple way to achive above

1. use `set +e` # Disable exit on non-zero

   ```
    sh ''''
    set +e
    ..
    '''
   ```
2. use OR || with cmd

   ```
    sh''''
    $CMD || echo "string doesn't exist."
    '''
   ```
3. use like below

   ```
    sh (
      script: 'YOUR SCRIPT',
      returnStatus: true
    )
   ```