# Getting ERROR: script returned exit code 1 while testing

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, babel-jest

Getting below build output- I need to know the reason behind FAILURE (all required packages were pre-installed)

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /opt/bitnami/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/testing-xx
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ npm -s run test
Test Suites: 4 passed, 4 total
Tests:       20 passed, 20 total
Snapshots:   1 obsolete, 3 passed, 3 total
Time:        6.88s
Ran all test suites.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please help me understand the reason and resolution (I have removed few outputs to shorten)

Comment: Tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61374958/jenkins-shell-script-returned-exit-code-1-when-the-searched-string-isnt-exsist

Comment: Looks like no expert/comment here